# Proving zero raised to the zeroth power is equal to one using the power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Its been a while since I have done math, so I wondering if there was a proof for this, if so what?

Is zero to the zero power 1? Or is it not defined?.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use power series?

Comment: $0^0$ is not defined.

Comment: @ graydad yes I was wondering if it could be proved using the power series.

Comment: Until $0^0$ is *defined*, there is nothing you can *prove* about it. And once it's defined, there is nothing left to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Limits don't apply to 0^0 any more than they do to 1^oo. Consider

```
lim(n->oo) (1+1/n)^n = e

lim(n->oo) (1+2/n)^n = e^2
```

Both are of the form 1^oo, but neither of these equals 1. And surely 1^oo = 1.

Also, various proposed limits for 0^0 come up with different answers:

```
lim(x->0) 0^x = 0

lim(x->0) x^0 = 1
```

So limits aren't helpful. But here's something that *is* helpful.

Consider

```
e^x = SUM(n=0->oo) x^n/n!
```

We are told that this is good for all real numbers, no? It's even good for complex numbers. Now, 0 is a real number. So this formula is good for e^0. But that only works if 0^0=1. (Oddly, the same books that tell us that 0^0 is "undefined" also tell us that the e^x formula above is good for all real numbers.)

Therefore, if you insist on calling 0^0 "undefined", you have to make an exception for using the above formula to calculate e^0. I doubt anyone is willing to do so! So 0^0=1.

This probably holds for any series in which you have the term a_0*x^0. We always equate this term as a_0, no matter what x is.

You get the same thing with the binomial theorem:

```
(a+b)^n = a^n + n * a^(n-1) * b + ... + b^n
```

In summation form you get

```
(a+b)^n = SUM(k=0->n) (n k) a^(n-k) b^k 

        = SUM(k=0->n) n!/(k!*(n-k)!) a^(n-k) b^k 

        = a^n b^0 + ... + a^0 b^n

        = a^n + ... + b^n
```

The summation version works because a^0 = 1 and b^0 = 1. Set a or b equal to zero and you get 0^0=1. And this is assuming n is a positive integer, where everyone agrees the theorem is true!

If you want to make the binomial theorem good for n=0, then 0^0=1 will do the job:

```
(a+b)^0 = 0!/(0!*0!) a^0 b^0 = a^0 b^0 = 1

0^0 = [a+(-a)]^0 = a^0 (-a)^0 = 1
```

No one has a problem defining 0! = 1. My high school book *Modern Introductory Analysis* additionally defines (n 0) = 1. So why not define (or conclude!) 0^0=1?

Some say you can't determine 0^0 because a^0 = a^1 / a^1 and with a=0 you can't do the division. But this need not be the defining condition! You can determine it otherhow, as I have above. The exponent rule used for this is

```
a^m * a^n = a^(m+n)
```

And a=0 satisfies it for integers m,n>=0. It satisfies the other exponent laws for non-negative exponents, too.

In conclusion, 0^0 = 1 unless you make x = 0 an exception to

```
e^x = SUM(n=0->oo) x^n/n!
```

and I really doubt anyone would.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably several posts out there on this. But there are two simple arguments:

1. For all positive real numbers $x$, $x^0 = 1$ where $x^y$ for positive $x$ is defined by $x^y := \exp(y\ln x)$. Hence it appeals to parsimony to set $0^0 = 1$, even though the definition does not extend to $x = 0$.
2. The limit of $x^x$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ from above is  $1$. Thus setting $0^0 = 1$ appeals to notions of (one-sided) continuity.

Answer (score 0):

0^0 is undefined. Consider the following limits:
$$\lim_{x\to0}x^x=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}0^x=\text{Does not exist}$$

Comment: The limit from the right exists.  Choose $\delta=1$.  Then, for all positive $\epsilon$ and $x>0$, $|0^x|=0<\epsilon$ for $0<x<\delta$.

Comment: @Dr. But the existence of a right hand limit does not imply that the limit exists.

Comment: MathNoob. Correct. But you wrote your first limit without designating the it is a right-handed one also.  That limit doesn't exist either.  In fact, for real-valued $x$, $x^x$ is not even defined.

Comment: However, $lim_{x\to 0} x^x$ does actually exist. 

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^x=\lim e^{x\log x}=e^{\lim x \log x}=e^0=1$$

Are you trying to say that the limit above does not exist?

Answer (score -2):

One way you can arrive at this equality is by evaluating $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\ln(x^x)}  \\ = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x\ln(x)}$$ Now using L'Hospital's rule on $x\ln(x) = \frac{ln(x)}{x^{-1}}$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{ln(x)}{x^{-1}} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-x^{-2}} \\ =\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{-x^2}{x} \\ = \lim_{x\to 0^+} =-x = 0$$ Hence $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x\ln(x)} = e^0 = 1$$ But the whole $0^0=1$ thing is pretty iffy. The right hand limit does not exist, for one thing.

Comment: Your limits don't exist.  In fact, for real-valued $x$, $x^x$ is not even defined for $x<0$.  The right-side limits do exist.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you for your input!

Comment: Graydad.  My pleasure.